# Crawl web auto complete keywords

Tags: web-crawler, google-crawlers

I am trying to get auto-complete keywords from the website.
The Target website is [https://www.daum.net/]

But I get those two errors.
What should I do about this?

```
items = jsonData['retext'][0]
KeyError: 'retext'
```

```
import requests
import json

keyword = input("키워드 : ")
url = f'https://ac.search.naver.com/nx/ac?q={keyword}&con=1&frm=nv&ans=2&r_format=json&r_enc=UTF-8&r_unicode=0&t_koreng=1&run=2&rev=4&q_enc=UTF-8&st=100&_callback=_jsonp_4'

headers = {
"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

req = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
retext = req.replace("_jsonp_4(","").replace(")","")
jsonData= json.loads(retext)
items = jsonData['items'][0]
for i in items:
    print(i[0])
```